# Python dll Extension Import

Tags: python, dll

I created extensions for my Python and created a `abcPython.dll`. How can I import this dll into my Python scripts?

I get an error message when I try to import it usin the following command

```
>>>import abcPython
>>>Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
     ImportError: No module named abcPython
>>>
```

I manually created a system environment variable named `PYTHONPATH` which stores the path to the `abcPython.dll`, but still the error remains.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Hello hello ... Did you get your problem fixed? Do you plan to accept an answer?

Answer (score 13):

Follow [Building C and C++ Extensions on Windows](http://docs.python.org/extending/windows.html#a-cookbook-approach) carefully - in sub-section 7, it says:

> The output file should be called spam.pyd (in Release mode) or spam_d.pyd (in Debug mode). The **extension .pyd** was chosen to avoid confusion with a system library spam.dll to which your module could be a Python interface
>   ...
>   *Changed in version 2.5:* Previously, file names like spam.dll (in release mode) or spam_d.dll (in debug mode) were also recognized.

Try the renaming your `DLL` to use a `.pyd` extension instead of `.dll`.

(thanks, [Peter Hansen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/221537/peter-hansen))

The reference points to a [`C` example](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/PC/example_nt/example.c?view=markup), which explicitly includes an INIT function,
`PyMODINIT_FUNC initexample(void)`. The resulting DLL should be renamed `example.pyd` :

```
#include "Python.h"

static PyObject *
ex_foo(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    printf("Hello, world\n");
    Py_INCREF(Py_None);
    return Py_None;
}

static PyMethodDef example_methods[] = {
    {"foo", ex_foo, METH_VARARGS, "foo() doc string"},
    {NULL, NULL}
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC
initexample(void)
{
    Py_InitModule("example", example_methods);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying

I renamed the .dll to .pyd and then tried the following

>>> import abcPython
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (PyInit_abcPython)
>>>

Comment: Follow instructions in the linked reference and DEFINE an init function!

Comment: Anybody asked the OP what version of Python he's using?

Answer (score 2):

Aarrgghh! Yet another 2.X/3.X gotcha. RTFErrorMessage:

`ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (PyInit_abcPython)`

Note the prefix: it's not **init**, it's **PyInit_**

See the [**3.1** docs](http://docs.python.org/3.1/extending/extending.html#the-module-s-method-table-and-initialization-function) ... "The initialization function must be named PyInit_name(), where name is the name of the module"

Answer (score 1):

Simple renaming of .dll to  .pyd did not help. I was using SWIG to create the extension module. I created a .pyd instead of creating a .dll module and that solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As an example: Imagine you have compiled OpenCV and have several *.dll and the cv2.pyd file.

You need to copy those files to 'DLLs' folder within the python directory.

Then import the module to check wether it is ok.